# Applying IF statement to entire column in R

Tags: r

I am trying to find a quick way to apply an IF statement to an entire column in R to create a new column of 1's and 0's depending on the statement. Specifically I want to calculate days with rainfall > 0 as wet days (1) and days with rainfall =0 as dry days (0). My data takes the form:

```
Day   Month   Year   Rainfall

1       1     1961    2.5

2       1     1961     0

3       1     1961    3.1

4       1     1961     0
```

I have created a loop as follows:

```
for (i in df$Rainfall){

WD=data.frame(ifelse(df$Rainfall>0,1,0)

}
```

This works, but is very slow. Is there a quicker way?

Many thanks.

Comment: There's no need for an explicit for loop here, since `ifelse` itselsf is vectorized (can be applied to vectors)

Comment: Many thanks for clearing this up - I though I needed to loop over the entire column, but I understand now why ifelse works without the loop. Thanks for your time in helping.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can wrap with `+` to the logical condition to coerce to binary vector.  It will be fast.

```
+(df$Rainfall >0)
```

Or if we are using `ifelse`, there is no need to loop, as it is vectorized

```
 ifelse(df$Rainfall > 0, 1, 0)
```